# Getting values from dynamic struct array

Tags: c++, c++11

I trying to create a program that receives and stores information about in a dynamic array of structures. And the program should sort and display the teams above average, average and below avaerage. This is my code so far. . So what I'm doing is I receive the user input the check the input before storing it in  dynamic structure array. Then finally I display all the information stored in the struct. Here's the output that i'm currently getting and I'm not sure why i'm getting this negative numbers.any ideas why?
Thanks

```
How many teams do you want to store? 2
Enter the name of the team 1:Vikings
Enter the team 1 percentage: 90
Enter the name of the team 2:PackersGreen Bay Packers
Enter the team 2 percentage: 80
Above Average :
Vikings 90%
PackersGreen Bay Packers 80%
Average :
 5.00136e-317%
None
Below Average : 
None
 9.25737e-306%
```

Here's my code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;


int main()
{

    struct aboveAverage
    {
        string name9;
        double percentage1;
    };

    struct average
    {
        string name10;
        double percentage2;
    };

    struct belowAverage
    {
        string name11;
        double percentage3;
    };

    int numOfteams;
    double userInput;

    cout << "How many teams do you want to store? ";
    cin >> numOfteams;
    cin.get();

    aboveAverage * arrayOfAboveAverage = new aboveAverage[numOfteams];
    average * arrayOfAverage = new average[numOfteams];
    belowAverage * arrayOfbelowAverage = new belowAverage[numOfteams];

    for (int i = 0; i < numOfteams; i++)
    {
    start:
        int x = i + 1;
        string name5;
        cout << "Enter the name of the team " << x << ":";
        getline(cin, name5);

        cout << "Enter the team " << x << " percentage: ";
        cin >> userInput;
        cin.get();



        if (userInput >= 66 && userInput <= 100)
        {
            arrayOfAboveAverage[i].percentage1 = userInput;
            arrayOfAboveAverage[i].name9 = name5;
        }

        else if (userInput <= 66 && userInput >= 33)
        {
            arrayOfAverage[i].name10 = name5;
            arrayOfAverage[i].percentage2 = userInput;
        }
        else if (userInput <= 33 && userInput >= 0)
        {
            arrayOfbelowAverage[i].name11 = name5;
            arrayOfbelowAverage[i].percentage3 = userInput;
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "Percent cannot be greater than 100" << endl;
            goto start;
        }


    }

        cout << "Above Average :" << endl;
        for (int j = 0; j < numOfteams; j++)
        {
            if (arrayOfAboveAverage[j].percentage1 != NULL ||
                arrayOfAboveAverage[j].name9 != "")
            {
                cout << arrayOfAboveAverage[j].name9 <<" ";
                cout << arrayOfAboveAverage[j].percentage1 <<"%"<< endl;
            }
            else
            {
                cout << "None" << endl;
            }

        }

        cout << "Average :" << endl;
        for (int j = 0; j < numOfteams; j++)
        {
            if (arrayOfAverage[j].percentage2 > 0 ||
                arrayOfAverage[j].name10 != "")
            {
                cout << arrayOfAverage[j].name10 <<" ";
                cout << arrayOfAverage[j].percentage2 <<"%"<<endl;
            }
            else
            {
                cout << "None" << endl;
            }
        }

        cout << "Below Average : "<< endl;
        for (int k = 0; k < numOfteams; k++)
        {
            if (arrayOfbelowAverage[k].percentage3 > 0 || 
                arrayOfbelowAverage[k].name11 != "")
            {
                cout << arrayOfbelowAverage[k].name11 << " ";
                cout << arrayOfbelowAverage[k].percentage3 <<"%"<< endl;
            }
            else
            {

                cout << "None" << endl;
            }
        }

    delete[] arrayOfAboveAverage;
    delete[] arrayOfAverage;
    delete[] arrayOfbelowAverage;

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: You really don't need 3 different arrays and 3 different types here.  You just need a Team type and then you can loop through that single array to find the above, below and average teams.

Comment: That works but the question wants us to create 3 different structures.

Comment: `5.00136e-317` isn't negative, it's positive but very small. You need to initialise the arrays properly or keep track of how many valid elements each contains.

Comment: Well that's silly.  Also off topic but you can use the same name for the variables inside the structs.  Each struct can have a `name` so you don't need things like `name11`.

Comment: @Becca Your teacher is a [gaaahck](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UnBlst3T7bY). You'd better run.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the following test

```
        if (arrayOfAverage[j].percentage2 > 0 ||
            arrayOfAverage[j].name10 != "")
```

When `arrayOfAverage` is uninitialized (as in your case) `name10` is initialized with the default value for a `std::string` (the empty string) but the value for `percentage2` (a `double`) is undefined.

You test both values with "or", not "and", so if `percentage2` is initialized with a positive value (by example: `5.00136e-317`) you enter in the `true` case.

Suggestion: when there is a useful value, the `name10` value isn't empty, so ignore `percentage2` and modify the test as follows

```
if ( ! arrayOfAverage[j].name10.empty() )
```

Same problem with the preceding

```
        if (arrayOfAboveAverage[j].percentage1 != NULL ||
            arrayOfAboveAverage[j].name9 != "")
```

and the following test

```
        if (arrayOfbelowAverage[k].percentage3 > 0 || 
            arrayOfbelowAverage[k].name11 != "")
```

My suggestion is to modify they as follows

```
if ( ! arrayOfAboveAverage[j].name9.empty() )

// ...

if ( ! arrayOfBelowAverage[j].name11.empty() )
```

Comment: for some reason my compiler doesn't accept the empty function. It errors out.@max66

Comment: @Becca - Very strange; can you transcribe the error? Anyway, you can use `size()`; something like `if ( arrayOfAverage[i].name10.size() )` (but if you can use `empty()` is (I suppose) better)